# How could I decode a key in a substitution cipher?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, encryption

```
public static String DecryptKey() {
        String decrypted = "";
        String Key = "YKPADOWNUTXLQGCFVSRZHIBJME"
        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        
        char [] alphaletters = Key.toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i<alphaletters.length(); i++) {
        //not sure what to put here in order to go through all of the letters in the key}


            return decrypted;
```

So in this code, I am trying to decrypt a key given in a substitution cipher. By decrypt I mean as the letter "Z" is where the letter "T" would usually be in the normal alphabet, in the decrypted string the letter "T" would be last in order to decrypt a message etc etc for each letter in the key. But im not sure how to do this so that the for loop will loop over each letter in the Key whilst checking its place in the normal alphabet, and then return the decrypted key.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the key so I presume you mean decrypt some text.

- Iterate over each character of the encrypted text.
- Find the characters position in the provided key.
- And substitute the character at that location in the alphabet string.

All the necessary methods are in the String class.

- Take the encrypted word `YFFLD`
- `Y` is at location `0` in the key.
- The character at `0` in the alphabet is `A`
- `F` is at location `15` in the key
- The character at `15` in the alphabet is `P`

Continuing in the above fashion, the clear text would be `APPLE`